# Decompress text string with zlib

Tags: c++, string, zlib, compression

I need to decode hexadecimal strings stored in zlib format. An example is:

> 1800000013000000eAFjYoAAZiDFCMQgGgQAAJwACg==

where 18000000 and 13000000 are the size of the uncompressed/compressed data (in this case 24 and 19).

Also I know that the rest of the string contains

> 020000000000000003000000010000000300000000000000

Where is the problem? following any tutorial like https://panthema.net/2007/0328-ZLibString.html compressing that string I get

> x?302@?P??

that in hexadecimal can be written as

> 783f3330324053f503f103ff5

That has nothing to do with my expected compressed string, so I didn't found the way to uncompress the original string (that is my final goal)

Thank you in advance for any tip!

PS. I'm using the decompress routine from
https://github.com/systemed/intersector/blob/master/helpers.cpp

It looks that the string has been encoded on base64 (thank you @zdenek and @Mark-Adler) I managed to decoded it with

```
BYTE *res;
int resSize = FromBase64Simple((BYTE*)actualData.c_str(),actualData.len(),res,sizeCompressed);
```

You can read the implementation from https://github.com/kengonakajima/luvit-base64/blob/master/base64.c

But this is not the problem since I can dump the result using

```
char* resChar = new char[resSize];
for(int i = 0;i<resSize;i++)
{
    int asciiCode = (BYTE)res[i];
    resChar[i]=char(asciiCode);
    char buffer [2];
    itoa (asciiCode,buffer,16);
    qDebug()<<"["<<i<<"]\t"<<asciiCode<<"\t"<<buffer;
}
```

I get the result of each byte in decimal and hexadecimal and both are ok. Hexadecimal looks like :

> 78 01 63 62 80 00 66 20 c5 08 c4 20 1a 04 00 00 9c 00 0a

But resChar is "x?cb?" that has nothing to do with the value said by @Mark-Adler "x?302@?P??" (where obviously '?' symbols are not printable ones), I really think that here is the problem, but my data seems to correspond with this table: https://www.asciitable.com/ and Mark's one doesn't also this web https://conv.darkbyte.ru/ returns the same results as my algorithm

I tried to decompress the string using the implementation said above but it failed (also tried https://gist.github.com/arq5x/5315739) but its decompressed value is a single character string ""

Here we go with the minimal reproducible case:

```
#include <string>

static char LookupDigits[] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //gap: ctrl chars
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, //gap: ctrl chars
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,           //gap: spc,!"#$%'()*
    62,                   // +
    0, 0, 0,             // gap ,-.
    63,                   // /
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, // 0-9
    0, 0, 0,             // gap: :;<
    99,                   //  = (end padding)
    0, 0, 0,             // gap: >?@
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
    17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25, // A-Z
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,    // gap: [\]^_`
    26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,
    43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51, // a-z
    0, 0, 0, 0,          // gap: {|}~ (and the rest...)
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};

int FromBase64Simple(const unsigned char* pSrc, int nLenSrc, unsigned char* pDst, int nLenDst)
{
    int nLenOut = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<nLenSrc; j += 4) {
        if (nLenOut > nLenDst) {
            return(0); // error, buffer too small
        }
        unsigned char s1 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];
        unsigned char s2 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];
        unsigned char s3 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];
        unsigned char s4 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];

        unsigned char d1 = ((s1 & 0x3f) << 2) | ((s2 & 0x30) >> 4);
        unsigned char d2 = ((s2 & 0x0f) << 4) | ((s3 & 0x3c) >> 2);
        unsigned char d3 = ((s3 & 0x03) << 6) | ((s4 & 0x3f) >> 0);

        *pDst++ = d1;  nLenOut++;
        if (s3 == 99) break;      // end padding found
        *pDst++ = d2;  nLenOut++;
        if (s4 == 99) break;      // end padding found
        *pDst++ = d3;  nLenOut++;
    }
    return(nLenOut);
}


int main()
{
    std::string inputData = "eAFjYoAAZiDFCMQgGgQAAJwACg==";


    //19 is hardcoded since I know its size prior to this call
    unsigned char res[19];
    int resSize = FromBase64Simple((unsigned char*)inputData.c_str(), inputData.size(), res, 19);


    for (int i = 0; i<resSize; i++)
    {
        int asciiCode = res[i];
        printf("[%i]\t%i\t%x\n", i, asciiCode, asciiCode);
    }
    printf("\n\nres: %s", (char*)res);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first string is BASE64 encoded

Comment: I thought that too but I didn't manage to decode it (I tried with https://www.base64decode.org/ )

Comment: You have to decode it as binary. The result should be `78 01 63 62 80 00 66 20 c5 08 c4 20 1a 04 00 00 9c 00 0a`. As you can see it has 19 characters. Now you have to decompress this binary blob with zlib. To deflate the data, you can try to follow this example: https://gist.github.com/arq5x/5315739

Comment: Sorry @zdenek I didn't understood how did you decode it.

You said just by using infstream.data_type =Z_BINARY; ? It didn't work for me

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Edit: I understood now, my bad sorr: first decode and after that decompress it!

Comment: No, unfortunatly the given result cannot be decompress neither :(

Comment: The x?302@?P?? is copied from _your_ question. It is not anything that _I_ generated. I have no idea what that was originally, since it's full of question marks. I only copied it point out to you what the question marks meant, since you erroneously then tried to convert the printed bytes to hex.

Comment: You do not need to complicate this problem by trying to generate more compressed data you don't know how to decompress. Simply get your first example to decompress (shown in your question both in Base64 starting with `eAF` and in hex starting with `78 01`. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Ok. You've almost got the idea. You need to provide an example of the _decompression not working_. As I've said several times, there is _nothing wrong_ with the hex string starting with `78 01`. That is a valid zlib stream that decompresses to exactly what you are expecting. The problem is that you are not able to decompress that for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me. I used the decompress function you linked and the base64 function you provided. I removed error checking and reformatted things a little to keep it shorter.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <zlib.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "zdll.lib")

static char LookupDigits[] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,62,0,0,0,63,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,
    0,0,0,99,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    20,21,22,23,24,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,
    37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
};

int FromBase64Simple(const unsigned char* pSrc, int nLenSrc, unsigned char* pDst, int nLenDst)
{
    int nLenOut = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<nLenSrc; j += 4)
    {
        if (nLenOut > nLenDst)
        {
            return(0); // error, buffer too small
        }
        unsigned char s1 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];
        unsigned char s2 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];
        unsigned char s3 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];
        unsigned char s4 = LookupDigits[*pSrc++];

        unsigned char d1 = ((s1 & 0x3f) << 2) | ((s2 & 0x30) >> 4);
        unsigned char d2 = ((s2 & 0x0f) << 4) | ((s3 & 0x3c) >> 2);
        unsigned char d3 = ((s3 & 0x03) << 6) | ((s4 & 0x3f) >> 0);

        *pDst++ = d1;  nLenOut++;
        if (s3 == 99) break;      // end padding found
        *pDst++ = d2;  nLenOut++;
        if (s4 == 99) break;      // end padding found
        *pDst++ = d3;  nLenOut++;
    }
    return(nLenOut);
}

std::string decompress_string(const std::string& str)
{
    z_stream zs;                        // z_stream is zlib's control structure
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));
    inflateInit(&zs);
    zs.next_in = (Bytef*)str.data();
    zs.avail_in = str.size();

    int ret;
    char outbuffer[32768];
    std::string outstring;
    do
    {
        zs.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(outbuffer);
        zs.avail_out = sizeof(outbuffer);
        ret = inflate(&zs, 0);
        if (outstring.size() < zs.total_out)
        {
            outstring.append(outbuffer, zs.total_out - outstring.size());
        }
    }
    while (ret == Z_OK);
    inflateEnd(&zs);
    return outstring;
}

int main()
{
    std::string inputData = "eAFjYoAAZiDFCMQgGgQAAJwACg==";
    //19 is hardcoded since I know its size prior to this call
    std::string res(19, '\0');
    FromBase64Simple((unsigned char*)inputData.c_str(), inputData.size(), (unsigned char*)res.data(), res.size());
    std::string d = decompress_string(res);
    for (int c : d)
    {
        printf("%02x", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `020000000000000003000000010000000300000000000000`

Comment: Oh my god! finally you spotted it! printf("%02x", c); was the key the data was ok but my interpretation of the buffer was not!

Answer (score 2):

The "eAFjYoAAZiDFCMQgGgQAAJwACg==" is Base64 encoded. You need to first decode that to the binary to get something that can be decompressed. That binary expressed in hex is:

```
78 01 63 62 80 00 66 20 c5 08 c4 20 1a 04 00 00 9c 00 0a
```

That is a valid zlib stream that decompresses to this, expressed in hex:

```
02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Your result of compression "x?302@?P??" was originally in binary, and cannot be printed. Those question marks are not really question marks in the original, but rather some other bytes that don't print. So don't print it. Your resulting attempt at converting the printed result to hex is incorrect, since you have the question marks (3f) in the hex.

Comment: I did it and I get in decimal
> 120 1 99 98 128 0 102 32 197 8 196 32 26 4 0 0 156 0 10

that is the same value as your hex version, also that's coherent with this website conversion: https://conv.darkbyte.ru/

Unfortunatly decompressing it with zlib doesn't return the desired string.

Comment: I've added to the original post the decompression routine, it fails with error -5 (incomplete or truncated stream)

Comment: I decoded it with zlib, so you are doing something wrong. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the `decompress_string()` routine you linked, so you must not be feeding the data that you think you're feeding it.

Comment: I used this code for get base64 (and for testing)
    BYTE *res;int resSize = FromBase64Simple((BYTE*)actualData.buffer(),actualData.len(),res,sizeCompressed);

    char* resChar = new char[resSize];
    for(int i = 0;i<resSize;i++)
    {
        int asciiCode = (BYTE)res[i];
        resChar[i]=char(asciiCode);
        char buffer [2];
        itoa (asciiCode,buffer,16);
        qDebug()<<"["<<i<<"]"<<asciiCode<<buffer;
    }

The result seems to be ok in hexadecimal and I tried by feeding with BYTE* res and with char* resChar without luck

Comment: Btw with that hexadecimal array (78 01...) I have no x?302... but xcb?

Comment: We can't figure this out from random code fragments. You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I ellaborated it more on the first post just by adding the urls of the base64 decoding, the uncompress used code and my tests to verify that the hexadecimal values are ok

char* resChar = new char[resSize];
for(int i = 0;i<resSize;i++)
{
    int asciiCode = (BYTE)res[i];
    resChar[i]=char(asciiCode);
    char buffer [2];
    itoa (asciiCode,buffer,16);
    qDebug()<<"["<<i<<"]\t"<<asciiCode<<"\t"<<buffer;
}

Comment: If you cannot provide an mcve, then I cannot help further. See the link for what that means.

Comment: Added a  minimal, complete, and verifiable example in the first post, thak you for your really valuable time Mark!

Comment: another user spotted printf("%02x", c); was the key the data was ok but my interpretation of the buffer was not!